# My Transactions are broken (3 and a half weeks since my first)

Tags: blockchain, blockchain.info

I have had to come here after Blockchain blocked me from their support for no apparent reason. I have sent two transactions totalling at $40 which have been running for 3 and a half weeks. I sent these one to Warthunder through Bitpay(game) (I will refer to this as my 1st transaction), and another 4 days latter to a new wallet I made with BitPay's Wallet service (I will refer to this as my 2nd transaction). Normally when you pay through Bitpay it shows it sees the transaction coming this did not happen with my 1st transaction, I am not familiar with the Bitpay wallet service so I do not know if it shows. Any way i have been on the Blockchain support centre for 2 and a half weeks and all they said was please wait and then they stopped responding to my posts for 3 days and then they suspended me for no reason. I got suspended today because last night I checked if my post had a response. I would love it if someone could help me.

1st Transaction: https://blockchain.info/tx/2ffeff9f8befe76056005a23cb71b6e81460d60fc68dd8480d754a16bdbc5130
2nd Transaction: https://blockchain.info/tx/1165ccf9c3667c32c89653daad188c99862441c3e31fe254c6a698a7c8a6c2ee

Comment: This is all that was shown to me when I tried to log in today to my account(my suspended account) [link](https://prnt.sc/fmm68g)

Comment: My first dust transaction [Dust 1](https://blockchain.info/tx/96c0ba5964b5ac1307f86cf9ac4493e290506ca0337d9d4d3b661fed9cdb258a) was accepted a few days ago, but my second is still stuck. [Dust 2](https://blockchain.info/tx/d5cf0512c3664913228b60699a4b6e954276da706b36a04358fcc8bd66d20381) I would like some help about how to get this one moving. I have tried to send a second transaction over it but because of how blockchain works I can't.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Both my dust transactions have been comfirmed, it is only a matter of time befor my actual transactions are free.

Answer (score 0):

There is an unconfirmed ancestor transaction upstream that pays 0.89 sat/Byte also creating an output that is barely over dust limit. The first and second transaction appear to make child-pays-for-parent transactions with 300 sat/Byte and 492 sat/Byte, but the zeroth transaction might be sufficiently "non-standard" to not be selected for a block.

It may be that blockchain.info mistook you for someone that tried to defraud a vendor on purpose, since creating dust outputs and building on top of low-fee ancestor transactions would be a simple strategy to exploit a merchant's acceptance of zero-confirmation transactions.

Comment: that was just a joke transaction to a friend. I am sending a second transaction over the first to try and get it canceled so it frees up. thank you for responding.